# Check nested objects with an array of keys

Tags: coffeescript

I've got an array (target) with keys to a series of nested objects. I need to make sure there is a object there before I set a value to it later on. This code is working but only so far as I can be bothered to repeat it.

How can I do this for *n* number of keys in the array without repeating this switch to infinity?

```
for t, index in target
    switch i
        when 1
            if object[target[0]] is undefined
                object[target[0]] = {}
        when 2
            if object[target[0]][target[1]] is undefined
                object[target[0]][target[1]] = {}
        when 3
            if object[target[0]][target[1]][target[2]] is undefined
                object[target[0]][target[1]][target[2]] = {}
        when 4
            if object[target[0]][target[1]][target[2]][target[3]] is undefined
                object[target[0]][target[1]][target[2]][target[3]] = {}
        when 5
            if object[target[0]][target[1]][target[2]][target[3]][target[4]] is undefined
                object[target[0]][target[1]][target[2]][target[3]][target[4]] = {}
        when 6
            if object[target[0]][target[1]][target[2]][target[3]][target[4]][target[5]] is undefined
                object[target[0]][target[1]][target[2]][target[3]][target[4]][target[5]] = {}
```

Comment: Look into tree iteration with recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*caveat* untested code from the top of my head. But this should work...

```
current = object
for t in target
  current = (current[t] ?= {})
```

Or a more javascripty version:

```
target.reduce ((o,t)-> o[t]?={}), object
```

The first one is more legible, the second more elegant imho (and does not pollute the scope with `current`).

Comment: Note that `Array::reduce` isn't available in all browsers. Here's an implementation you can use as a fallback: http://www.diveintojavascript.com/core-javascript-reference/the-array-object/array-reduce